# Signed Java applet running another .jar on linux server

Tags: java, linux, apache, applet

I have searched high and low for an answer but to no avail.

I have a service that is hosted on my linux server (apache).  Rather than ssh-ing in to launch the service, I created a web portal with an applet to launch/shutdown the service and collect output of the service.

I created the applet and noticed that during testing, everything worked swimmingly with shell commands (bash) such as:

```
ping -c 25 wwww.google.com
```

but not:

```
/user/bin/java -jar MyService.jar
```

The commands are being run with this method:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/php -v");
```

There is plenty of security to get to the portal, so I am not too worried about that as of now since this service is not advertised or available to anyone.

How come I can invoke shell commands but not execute the .jar I wish to or even a script to execute the .jar?

I scoured the Oracle documentation of Applets but there is no mention as to what user or permissions an applet has or would need for this to work.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

edit0:

Finally had time to do some reading and.  ProcessBuilder seems like the easier/more modern way to make this happen.

I got "java -version" to work but running a .jar is still not working.  According to all of the examples that I've read, this should work:

```
public class Proxy implements Runnable {
final JTextArea output;
private ProcessBuilder pb;
private final String[] args = {"/usr/bin/java", "-version"};

Proxy(JTextArea area) { 
    output = area;
}


void fire() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    //pb.directory(new File("/opt/myBin/"));

    final Process p = pb.start();

    InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

    InputStream errorStream = p.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);

    BufferedReader bufferedStdOut = new BufferedReader(isr);
    BufferedReader bufferedStdErr = new BufferedReader(esr);

    String buffer = null;

    while((buffer = bufferedStdOut.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(buffer);
    }

    buffer = null;
    while((buffer = bufferedStdErr.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(buffer);
    }
```

}

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        this.fire();
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        output.append(ex.toString() + "\n");
        Logger.getLogger(Proxy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: *"The commands are being run with this method:"*  As a tip:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  BTW - You do realize an applet cannot be run like an executable jar, as seen above, right?

Comment: *"..there is no mention as to what user or permissions.."*  Launching external processes like above requires `all-permissions`.  An external process is beyond Java's security manager, so the JVM won't allow it in anything less than fully trusted code.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I will give that a read, thanks.  The applet is being run in the traditional sense, embedded in a page.  I am trying to get it to run a different .jar.

Also, its not a school project, but merely a personal one.  I wan't to be able to remotely launch this service and also to learn something.  I actually read part of that article that you referenced :).  Applet wasn't my first choice as I tried to do it with php and ajax but needed multiple threads.  I didn't really explore a cgi either.